# Magnetic force on wire of arbitrary shape is same b/w two points

Tags: magnetic-fields

So i was told that the magnetic force on a current carrying wire  b/w two points is constant and irrespective of the shape of the wire (Taking an uniform magnetic field). I was looking for proofs on the net and i couldn't find one which mathematically proved it for any general squiggly line b/w two points.

I came up with this explanation. If the length vector at any point along the wire can be broken down into a horizontal and vertical component, the force wrt to the vertical components cancel out while the horizontal components' forces add up and as the sum of all the horizontal components is the length b/w the fixed points, the F only depends on the distance b/w fixed points. My question being if this logic is correct, and if so how can we mathematically say for sure.